# Upload Attachment field to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, attachments, image-upload, android

I am trying to upload an Attachment (file image in jpg format) to a table of SharePoint 2013 throught an Android POST Request.

That table has different columns and one of them is of type Attachment (with the clip icon). However, on the body of the request, I am not being able to upload any data to AttachmentFiles because I don't know how to do it (what is the format of the AttachmentFile I should send?). The code of my request and response is the following:

```
12-07 12:44:38.450 6133-7240/testapp.com.testapp D/OkHttp: --> POST https://urltest.es/iot/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('RESULTS_COMMENTS')/items?$orderby=Signed%20asc&$top=100000 http/1.1
12-07 12:44:38.450 6133-7240/testapp.com.testapp D/OkHttp: {"AttachmentFiles":"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Attachment20171207_124428-1813646694.jpg","FORMId":3,"COMMENT":"mejdkd","__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.RESULTS_x005f_COMMENTSListItem"},"USER_LOGIN":"testuser"}
12-07 12:44:38.500 6133-7240/testapp.com.testapp D/OkHttp: <-- 400 Bad Request https://urltest.es/iot/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('RESULTS_COMMENTS')/items?$orderby=Signed%20asc&$top=100000 (52ms)
12-07 12:44:38.500 6133-7240/testapp.com.testapp D/OkHttp: {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of a navigation property; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected."}}}
```

If I remove the "AttachmentFiles" element from the request the petition works correctly and the item is created (201) in the table (but without Attachment).

I know that I am only passing the file path, but I tried to send the file in Base64 or as a byte array and it did not work either. Anyone knows how can the upload be done?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE!

I tried to Attach the file in a separated call, as suggested and now the response from the server is 200 (OK), but when I try to recover the file, the server returns nothing (0x0 image in the GET request). The log from the new call is the following:

```
D: --> POST https://test.com.es/sites/iot/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('RESULTS')/items(118)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='Attachment20171227_115411-1298092432.jpg') http/1.1
D: Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
D: Content-Length: 959012
D: X-RequestDigest: 0xBF892F87A74FD3F28E7FE5E8FAA970387C9B33DB05F99C61CC23553E07D394202CB20CBB1B9C0B81272539B72378010FE532192C516AA9F697CF64D8CE464454,27 Dec 2017 10:59:13 -0000
D: Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
D: [-1,-40,-1,-31,14,-12,69,120,105,102,0,0,73,73,42,0,8,0,0,0,13,0,0,1,4,0,1,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,1,1,4,0,1,0,0,0,-128,4,0,0,15,1,2,0,8,0,0,0,-86,0,0,0,16,1,2,0,8,0,0,0,-78,0,0,0,18,1,3,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,26,1,5,0,1,0,0,0,-70,0,0,0,27,1,5,0,1,0,0,0,-62,0,0,0,40,1,3,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,49,1,2,0,13,0,0,0,-54,0,0,0,50,1,2,0,20,0,0,0,-40,0,0,0,19,2,3,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,105,-121,4,0,1,0,0,0,-20,0,0,0,37,-120,4,0,1,0,0,0,8,3,0,0,26,3,0,0,83,65,77,83,85,78,71,0,83,77,45,84,51,54,53,0,72,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,72,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,84,51,54,53,88,88,85,49,66,80,75,50,0,0,50,48,49,55,58,49,50,58,50,55,32,49,49,58,53,52,58,49,54,0,25,0,-102,-126,5,0,1,0,0,0,30,2,0,0,-99,-126,5,0,1,0,0,0,38,2,0,0,34,-120,3,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,39,-120,3,0,1,0,0,0,-112,1,0,0,0,-112,7,0,4,0,0,0,48,50,50,48,3,-112,2,0,20,0,0,0,46,2,0,0,4,-112,2,0,20,0,0,0,66,2,0,0,1,-111,7,0,4,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,5,-110,5,0,1,0,0,0,86,2,0,0,7,-110,3,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,8,-110,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,-110,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,-110,5,0,1,0,0,0,94,2,0,0,124,-110,7,0,98,0,0,0,-120,2,0,0,0,-96,7,0,4,0,0,0,48,49,48,48,1,-96,3,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,-96,4,0,1,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,3,-96,4,0,1,0,0,0,-128,4,0,0,5,-96,4,0,1,0,0,0,-22,2,0,0,23,-94,3,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,-93,7,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,-92,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,-92,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,-92,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,-92,2,0,33,0,0,0,102,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,4,1,0,0,100,0,0,0,50,48,49,55,58,49,50,58,50,55,32,49,49,58,53,52,58,49,54,0,50,48,49,55,58,49,50,58,50,55,32,49,49,58,53,52,58,49,54,0,20,1,0,0,100,0,0,0,23,1,0,0,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,1,0,7,0,4,0,0,0,48,49,48,48,2,0,4,0,1,0,0,0,0,32,1,0,12,0,4,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,5,0,1,0,0,0,90,0,0,0,64,0,4,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,0,4,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,2,0,4,0,0,0,82,57,56,0,2,0,7,0,4,0,0,0,48,49,48,48,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,4,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,1,4,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,4,0,1,0,0,0,32,1,0,0,3,1,3,0,1,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,18,1,3,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,26,1,5,0,1,0,0,0,-116,3,0,0,27,1,5,0,1,0,0,0,-108,3,0,0,40,1,3,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,2,4,0,1,0,0,0,-100,3,0,0,2,2,4,0,1,0,0,0,80,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,72,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,72,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,-40,-1,-37,0,-124,0,23,16,17,20,17,14,23,20,19,20,26,24,23,27,34,57,37,34,31,31,34,70,50,53,41,57,83,73,87,86,81,73,80,79,91,103,-125,111,91,97,124,99,79,80,114,-100,116,124,-120,-116,-109,-107,-109,89,110,-95,-83,-96,-113,-85,-125,-112,-109,-115,1,24,26,26,34,30,34,67,37,37,67,-115,94,80,94,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-115,-1,-64,0,17,8,1,32,2,0,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,-1,-60,1,-94,0,0,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,16,0,2,1,3,3,2,4,3,5,5,4,4,0,0,1,125,1,2,3,0,4,17,5,18,33,49,65,6,19,81,97,7,34,113,20,50,-127,-111,-95,8,35,66,-79,-63,21,82,-47,-16,36,51,98,114,-126,9,10,22,23,24,25,26,37,38,39,40,41,42,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,-125,-124,-123,-122,-121,-120,-119,-118,-110,-109,-108,-107,-106,-105,-104,-103,-102,-94,-93,-92,-91,-90,-89,-88,-87,-86,-78,-77,-76,-75,-74,-73,-72,-71,-70,-62,-61,-60,-59,-58,-57,-56,-55,-54,-46,-45,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-31,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-15,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,1,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,17,0,2,1,2,4,4,3,4,7,5,4,4,0,1,2,119,0,1,2,3,17,4,5,33,49,6,18,65,81,7,97,113,19,34,50,-127,8,20,66,-111,-95,-79,-63,9,35,51,82,-16,21,98,114,-47,10,22,36,52,-31,37,-15,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,-126,-125,-124,-123,-122,-121,-120,-119,-118,-110,-109,-108,-107,-106,-105,-104,-103,-102,-94,-93,-92,-91,-90,-89,-88,-87,-86,-78,-77,-76,-75,-74,-73,-72,-7
D: 1,-70,-62,-61,-60,-59,-58,-57,-56,-55,-54,-46,-45,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-1,-38,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,-27,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,
D: -118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,
D: -94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,40,-94,-118,0,-1,-39,-1,-37,0,-124,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,4,3,3,2,3,5,4,5,5,5,4,4,4,5,6,7,6,5,5,7,6,4,4,6,9,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,5,6,9,10,9,8,10,7,8,8,8,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,2,2,4,8,5,4,5,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,-1,-64,0,17,8,4,-128,8,0,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,-1,-60,1,-94,0,0,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,16,0,2,1,3,3,2,4,3,5,5,4,4,0,0,1,125,1,2,3,0,4,17,5,18,33,49,65,6,19,81,97,7,34,113,20,50,-127,-111,-95,8,35,66,-79,-63,21,82,-47,-16,36,51,98,114,-126,9,10,22,23,24,25,26,37,38,39,40,41,42,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,-125,-124,-123,-122,-121,-120,-119,-118,-110,-109,-108,-107,-106,-105,-104,-103,-102,-94,-93,-92,-91,-90,-89,-88,-87,-86,-78,-77,-76,-75,-74,-73,-72,-71,-70,-62,-61,-60,-59,-58,-57,-56,-55,-54,-46,-45,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-31,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-15,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,1,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,17,0,2,1,2,4,4,3,4,7,5,4,4,0,1,2,119,0,1,2,3,17,4,5,33,49,6,18,65,81,7,97,113,19,34,50,-127,8,20,66,-111,-95,-79,-63,9,35,51,82,-16,21,98,114,-47,10,22,36,52,-31,37,-15,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,-126,-125,-124,-123,-122,-121,-120,-119,-118,-110,-109,-108,-107,-106,-105,-104,-103,-102,-94,-93,-92,-91,-90,-89,-88,-87,-86,-78,-77,-76,-75,-74,-73,-72,-71,-70,-62,-61,-60,-59,-58,-57,-56,-55,-54,-46,-45,-44,-43,-42,-41,-40,-39,-38,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26,-25,-24,-23,-22,-14,-13,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-1,-38,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,-2,12,-103,-106,48,100,39,44,58,123,-44,112,43,73,-106,97,-64,-28,15,74,-120,43,101,92,-74,-12,-49,79,90,-77,-106,18,40,64,112,78,15,-75,0,69,41,-111,-127,-63,24,3,-91,58,33,-71,48,-53,-116,117,-55,-21,-17,82,-55,2,-86,-105,13,-72,-98,72,21,18,13,-49,-110,112,-125,-88,-51,105,-54,-102,1,-78,-60,-64,-4,-65,112,-14,78,122,82,-84,114,18,54,-126,-15,103,-65,106,-98,-31,89,-41,41,38,16,-13,-45,-83,42,-18,-122,52,102,99,-77,-81,38,-77,122,104,3,-60,74,-55,-67,31,-112,57,-56,-23,84,-98,85,117,100,-5,-104,56,27,-115,75,114,-93,102,-11,-56,82,50,49,-34,-88,-58,55,58,-126,51,-98,-108,1,42,-112,-116,62,124,-127,-63,-26,-99,35,9,9,-38,54,-29,-100,-98,-11,17,93,-116,1,-11,-32,-44,-62,55,39,111,0,30,-124,-98,-76,0,-127,23,-27,-63,5,-121,115,72,99,27,-55,110,112,51,-113,90,112,-73,-112,74,7,92,-98,-75,59,91,21,-112,-68,-121,11,-114,-108,1,81,88,56,-38,125,112,9,-87,-104,44,15,-61,99,35,32,83,-92,-122,53,96,66,-19,-49,35,35,-83,71,38,10,46,87,-111,-23,64,19,-18,50,-123,103,114,72,56,25,61,-86,-92,-84,102,127,-112,101,71,0,-45,-74,-71,1,-70,-116,113,-51,68,55,35,-4,-65,-107,0,78,-111,20,82,-17,-48,-116,-113,106,72,-54,-69,28,110,32,-10,39,-91,57,-117,75,-75,27,-27,29,121,-17,77,49,-7,114,21,4,15,112,104,2,72,98,38,97,25,-56,82,121,3,-75,37,-28,80,-59,62,-56,-37,-127,-41,39,-67,47,-17,50,113,-115,-64,113,-118,-84,-22,73,36,-32,30,-89,38,-128,45,-108,-113,106,49,113,-57,35,29,-22,45,-8,73,50,112,65,-56,7,-46,-91,107,117,72,-105,115,29,-60,115,-98,-43,89,19,-51,-108,33,-32,99,-75,0,34,43,57,44,71,-54,6,9,52,-19,-63,89,118,12,-25,-118,-79,113,19,-96,41,31,-35,-57,34,-104,14,66,29,-127,112,113,-116,80,2,-77,-58,-50,-120,-21,-100,-11,52,-109,91,4,113,-77,-112,64,35,53,24,80,73,98,14,-29,-56,-55,-89,-7,-116,-103,102,5,-101,24,3,-46,-128,36,14,-84,-97,-68,-64,-63,-64,24,-90,72,99,80,-92,40,-25,-34,-107,68,102,9,36,35,107,-125,-64,-57,90,-81,-69,-52,93,-89,10,71,67,-21,64,18,-128,11,12,113,-21,-19,83,73,18,21,109,-83,-12,57,-86,-101,29,87,-27,-7,-78,122,-114,-43,56,97,-75,55,-15,-127,-64,-
D: 49,-21,64,21,-100,-2,-19,122,-25,60,-15,90,0,-96,-127,68,121,43,-112,121,-20,106,-77,-93,-74,20,0,20,-98,-44,-93,112,79,40,2,72,57,-29,-75,0,70,-51,-105,42,49,-100,-32,-44,-47,66,25,11,-109,-116,19,-63,-89,-58,-125,118,88,99,-116,28,-118,-123,-25,-38,-52,-120,50,9,-17,64,18,44,113,-78,-79,57,12,7,76,-43,29,-66,-100,-100,-12,-57,90,-99,-101,37,64,-62,-25,-126,79,122,66,-31,126,-23,12,65,-57,34,-128,36,-14,-105,-54,44,120,-57,99,-38,-102,-116,89,66,15,-70,79,56,29,105,85,-39,-43,85,-113,83,-64,3,-83,57,-99,81,-16,21,84,-11,-6,80,4,74,28,-71,-14,-55,24,-32,-112,58,-45,-111,-128,44,101,57,62,-121,-67,73,28,-121,123,-116,14,-99,-121,90,102,-43,-35,-106,-5,-92,-13,-114,-44,0,-60,-109,-100,40,98,79,64,42,-53,-88,100,77,-57,107,30,125,-59,63,-55,68,27,-94,-32,-11,4,-98,-107,89,60,-58,-109,115,-18,-50,122,-102,0,87,98,-123,87,61,58,-32,117,-87,11,-61,-111,-123,-6,-29,-67,72,97,15,38,-3,-61,104,-32,-125,-38,-85,-54,-58,25,8,11,-112,78,70,123,-48,4,-101,119,47,-18,-14,57,-4,-22,16,-62,41,50,-5,-117,103,28,118,-89,-93,-77,99,39,103,57,-64,-17,78,45,-119,126,101,-56,35,-126,104,-80,16,-68,-69,-97,57,-58,120,-50,105,-56,98,66,14,114,115,-55,52,-42,80,-46,49,-58,59,-114,58,-48,80,22,92,-12,61,-3,104,1,93,99,71,44,-92,17,-116,-116,-114,-76,7,82,124,-62,57,3,24,21,12,-121,-26,96,56,0,-32,15,74,124,101,66,18,-39,-21,-126,113,-46,-115,-74,2,68,59,-61,-29,-114,115,-125,77,117,37,-63,98,74,-114,-98,-43,41,-115,91,12,-92,21,-57,110,-43,3,-85,33,-21,-100,-10,-12,-96,9,124,-91,-28,-77,109,-56,-29,53,2,-95,-36,70,125,-78,59,-44,-83,-9,1,-2,60,126,116,70,-121,60,-74,59,-48,3,35,-5,-81,-23,-21,79,120,-48,13,-22,-8,108,100,10,-107,-93,46,-37,64,-38,-89,-112,125,106,-77,67,32,102,24,60,117,38,-128,35,82,67,103,-97,-62,-89,18,40,87,-7,115,-111,-126,79,106,-118,49,-55,-10,-21,-19,79,8,89,9,-32,0,113,-49,106,0,100,105,-26,54,63,95,74,122,-88,-13,2,6,24,-50,9,35,-91,73,26,-108,-34,55,116,25,-23,77,68,85,-109,-26,-55,66,51,-102,0,89,2,38,87,-82,122,31,74,-127,113,-45,4,-28,-15,-114,-11,97,-54,41,-7,121,0,-28,19,-34,-109,-121,27,-108,17,-49,52,0,-101,7,32,-74,-46,6,64,29,-22,24,-48,-69,0,-71,-11,-29,-75,72,20,17,-110,114,65,-91,-53,41,96,-99,79,4,-114,-44,1,98,53,116,66,91,28,-16,13,66,85,70,-47,-98,-121,-98,105,83,98,-97,-103,-40,2,59,-44,77,27,22,37,121,29,65,52,1,62,-63,-55,-37,-58,51,-41,-83,87,64,12,-104,98,113,-100,84,-118,36,-124,-114,9,4,113,-125,72,-88,-37,-73,-74,65,7,52,0,-10,-115,68,-125,-26,24,35,3,61,-87,14,-60,86,92,-125,-20,41,-114,-114,-51,-109,-116,-102,104,-113,61,-2,-76,-46,-69,-80,15,-124,49,-49,36,33,-29,25,-95,-58,1,-25,-114,-89,21,32,68,78,-67,-24,-33,-75,-126,-72,-54,-98,-122,-101,-117,91,-127,25,93,-85,-14,-100,-125,-33,20,-59,125,-84,9,94,65,-28,-43,-110,-103,44,-96,97,0,-56,34,-104,-37,72,-64,4,96,96..............]
D: --> END POST (959012-byte body)
I: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 128360(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(14MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 15MB/26MB, paused 1.906ms total 151.953ms
D: <-- 200 OK https://test.com.es/sites/iot/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('RESULTS')/items(118)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='Attachment20171227_115411-1298092432.jpg') (1035ms)
D: Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
D: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
D: Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8
D: Expires: Tue, 12 Dec 2017 11:00:18 GMT
D: Last-Modified: Wed, 27 Dec 2017 11:00:18 GMT
D: Vary: Accept-Encoding
D: Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
D: X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
D: SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 883
D: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
D: SPRequestGuid: e29c3a9e-e928-f0f7-70ed-205970d9766b
D: request-id: e29c3a9e-e928-f0f7-70ed-205970d9766b
D: X-RequestDigest: 0x6805AE58194C565F443FCEE1A7A119F1D0B46E55CEA73B39BACBF80F86BBD06BB2FE53B91A71D5653266B5C5409612CE80460CE4CC5DBD3A73119B684A7AD56C,27 Dec 2017 11:00:18 -0000
D: X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
D: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
D: MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4569
D: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
D: X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
D: Date: Wed, 27 Dec 2017 11:00:19 GMT
D: {"d":{"__metadata":{"id":"Web/Lists(guid'1be125bd-2557-4298-97c2-5d55ca3a9f49')/Items(118)/AttachmentFiles('Attachment20171227_115411-1298092432.jpg')","uri":"https://test.com.es/sites/iot/_api/Web/Lists(guid'1be125bd-2557-4298-97c2-5d55ca3a9f49')/Items(118)/AttachmentFiles('Attachment20171227_115411-1298092432.jpg')","type":"SP.Attachment"},"FileName":"Attachment20171227_115411-1298092432.jpg","ServerRelativeUrl":"/sites/iot/Lists/RESULTS/Attachments/118/Attachment20171227_115411-1298092432.jpg"}}
D: <-- END HTTP (548-byte body)
```

UPDATE 2:
I tried to generate the bytearray as following:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
        bosCommentResult.getAttachmentFile().getAbsolutePath());

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 2, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

But the result is the same, when I try to see the image file from the direct link generated BASE_URL/RESULTS/Attachments/idattachment/Attachment.png it contains errors and I cannot see anything. (Note that if I print the Bitmap inside an ImageView the image shows correctly).

Comment: You should consider posting your solution in an Answer post instead of your question. This way, it will be easier for others to find it.

Comment: @user3429953 please add a separate answer so I can award the bounty to you.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I created an answer with all the details of the solution. Hope it help future Android developers!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! After a lot of tries I finally could upload an attachment image file. The first thing to notice is that the attachment cannot be uploaded at the same time than the other info of the POST, so it's a completely separated POST request (as @arsalan-adam-khatri suggested) using the ID that the SharePoint returns after creating the new row in the table.

The new call should be similar to:

```
https://BASE_URL/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TABLE_NAME')/items(ROW_ID_NUMBER)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='NAME_OF_ATTACHMENT')
```

Note that it also to be added the following header:

```
"X-RequestDigest": digestValue
```

Then, the final thing to do is create the body of the POST, which should be the file byte buffer to be attached. This is the most complex part of the procedure, since I tried a lot of things that did not work:

- Image file as File
- Image encoded in Base64 as String
- Image as byte array (byte[])
- Image as BufferedOutputStream
- Image as Input/Output Stream

And a lot of other similar solutions that none of them work.

BUT finally I found a solution. The first thing to notice about the solution is that I am using the dependencies of **Retrofit and OkHttp3** in order to generate the API Service, the SharePoint calls, intercept the responses, etc. Taking this into account, the body of the request should be a RequestBody object (given by the OkHttp3 dependency), created as you can see in the code below:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] buf;
buf = new byte[in.available()];
while (in.read(buf) != -1) {

}
// Note that creating the image as MultipartBody.Part does not work. 
// Also does not work to create the RequestBody with MediaType.parse("image/*")
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody
       .create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), buf);
```

And then, the call to the SharePoint (with Retrofit) is something like:

```
@POST(ApiUrls.Endpoint.UPLOAD_IMAGE_ATTACHMENT)
Observable<Void> uploadImageAttachment(
        @Header(ApiUrls.Param.X_REQUEST_DIGEST) String digestValue,
        @Path(ApiUrls.Param.RESULT_ID) int resultId,
        @Path(ApiUrls.Param.FILE_NAME) String fileName,
        @Body RequestBody attachment);
```

Where:

```
ApiUrls.Endpoint.UPLOAD_IMAGE_ATTACHMENT = The URL endpoint which is a constant value (for example, "https://test.com/es/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('COMMENTS')/items('{resultId}')/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='{filename}')")
resultID = The ROW_ID_NUMBER (for example, 108)
filename = The NAME_OF_ATTACHMENT (for example, "attach.png")
attachment = The requestBody just created
```

Hope it helps!!

PD: I do not know how to do this without the Retrofit and OkHttp3 dependencies (that are very commonly used), so any extensions of this solution without using them will be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Following is jQuery example of attaching file via REST

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload1" />
<input type="submit" id="buttonClick" onClick="buttonSubmitClick()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonSubmitClick() {

    event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
    event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

     var file = $('#fileUpload1')[0].files[0];

      var getFileBuffer = function(file) {

       var deferred = $.Deferred();
       var reader = new FileReader();

       reader.onload = function(e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
       }

       reader.onerror = function(e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
       }

       reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

       return deferred.promise();
      };

       getFileBuffer(file).then(function(buffer) {

       $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(" + listName + ")/items(" + itemId + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        method: 'POST',
        data: buffer,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
         "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
         "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
         "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
            {
                console.log("success");
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
            // STOP LOADING SPINNER
        }
       });

      }); 
  }

  </script>
```

So in short you need to define only File Name in the request URL and than headers will contain the file type and file contents.

You will first create the item and using it's newly generated ID, again make a request to attach file.

**UPDATE**

Above I have added a working example which I added as in SharePoint page using Content Editor Web Part. Few changes here and there and it worked.

Below is the result when I log the buffer:

[image: Array Buffer]

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks for the quick response! What a shame it cannot be done in the same POST than the other elements of the item :(

Comment: I tried to do it, but I still cannot find the way to establish the buffer in Java. What kind of object has it to be? Thanks!

Comment: @user3429953 I have added the function to get the file buffer

Comment: thanks @arsalan-adam-khatri I still cannot find what is the Android (Java) version of that code, but I will try. Maybe you can help me even more, if you debug the body (data) of the request, the body is an array of bytes? or a json? or an object with inside an array of bytes?

Comment: @user3429953 it should be byte array, check if byte array works otherwise I will check what is it returning

Comment: Hello again @arsalan-adam-khatri I coudnt do it, the upload returns me a 201 status, but when I try to see the image in the SharePoint it says that the file contains errors...

Comment: but you see your file in List Item attachments?

Comment: yes, the name is correct but the link is broken because the file is corrupted... the same happens when i have no body

Comment: @user3429953 I have added a working example from jQuery / JavaScript form page. I don't have Android environment otherwise I would have tested an Android code.

Comment: thanks for all your help @arsalan-adam-khatri ! I will try this between today and tomorrow and I will keep you informed :)

Comment: As you can see in my update, sending an array of bytes (byte[]) is still not working with your same headers... I am lost with the sharepoint at this point, still do not know what kind of object he wants to attach any kind of file

Comment: I'm sorry brother, please untick my answer.. and I will create a bounty on your question for others to answer

Comment: ok, any help is always welcome even if we could not do it! I think the key it's in the body of the request (he likes the ArrayBuffer but not the byte[] of Android)

Comment: @user3429953 I have started a bounty in your question, let's see how it goes.

Comment: in Java you have to convert the image to Bitmap, then to ByteArrayOutputStream using Bitmap.compress

Comment: Hello @Marco I tried your solution, but still cannot see the content of the image attachment. I will update the answer with the code but the things I tried are: Send as body of the POST request the ByteArrayOutputStream, the Bitmap and the bytearrayoutputstream.tobytearray() and nothing worked.

Comment: Look I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection

Comment: Hello again! I finally found the solution using Retrofit and RxJava, as seen in this reference link https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1217 

I will update the answer right now. 

Thank you both for your help!

Comment: Glad you found the solution mate and thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

For people who are reading in 2023, simple answer is just don't use multipart upload. SharePoint gets confused with multipart uploads. use simple upload if using retrofit with okhttp3